# iOS NSData contentsOfUrl return nil on real device iPhone5s but work well on simulator

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata

I got a problem like the title.

```
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
let filename = url.lastPathComponent
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
```

These code are work well on simulator but when I run it on my iphone5s it crash because the function NSData(contentsofurl: url) return nil.

I have check this is good:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: "I have check this is good": No it's not good, it's bad. It's awful. It disables transport security. It's meant to let you continue development in other areas while you fix your problems with transport security.

Comment: sorry if let you feel not so good. I am new to ios and just want to run it ok